# shell scripting in linux using idel command

Tags: linux, shell

i need help
i want to write a shell script that will display the name of each ordinary file in
the given directory and invites the user to decide interactively
whether or not the file should be deleted.
 The script should also ask the user if the "Interactive file deletion"
should be applied recursively to sub directories of the given
directory.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with

```
 rm -ri <path>
```